# Convert nonintegers into integers python

Tags: python, integer

Sorry for any earlier ambiguity.  I need to test whether a given variable is an integer (mathematical not pythonic definition of integer if there is a difference).  I currently use the function

isinstance( [var], ( int, long ) ).

When given 2 as the variable (var) it prints true.  However, when given 2.0 it prints False.

This is a problem, as I need to have a  function that will respond that 2.0 , 2.00 , 2.000 and any number numerically equal to an integer is an integer.  While responding that numbers not numerically equivalent (1.4, 3.14, 2.7 etc) are non-integers  Are there any functions or specific codes I could use to achieve this?

Note: I believe, based on previous feedback that "pythonically" speaking 2.0 is, in fact, not an integer.  Even so, it is mathematically, the function must return that it is.

Comment: Have you read http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex?

Comment: Are you by any chance evaluating the user's input directly by using either `eval(raw_input('Enter an integer: '))` or `input('Enter an integer: ')`?

Comment: Why was this question unclear?  I don't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not convert it to an int?

```
>>> int(2.00)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am aware that it is easier to easier to ask forgiveness than
>   permission in python but in this case it is necessary

Offcourse, you can `ask for forgiveness here rather than permission`. First assume you have an integer, and if its not, `ask for forgiveness` and repeat.

```
while True:
    try:
        value = int(raw_input()) 
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

But if you still want to `ask for permission`, you may rather want to use isinstance in the following fashion assuming, a float can be converted to an integer

```
isinstance(2.0,(int,long, float))
```

Comment: The function "isinstance(var,(int,long, float))" was exactly what i needed!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstood the question in my first answer.  If you are trying to distinguish between 7.00 and 7.01 you could use something like this, which will work up to a certain precision:

```
def likeint(value):
    return value - int(value) == 0


>>> likeint(8.0)
True
>>> likeint(7.0000000001)
False
>>> likeint(7.0000000000)
True
>>> likeint(7)
True
```